# Laravel 5 nested relation with condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've these tables:

Users

|id|role_id|clan_id|

Roles

|id|slug|

Clans

|id|

I need to grab all Users where slug is for example 'leader'

How can I do it?

What I got so far:

```
class clan extends Model{
    public function leader() 
    {
        $leader = User::whereHas('role', function($query) {
            $query->where('slug', 'leader');
        })->where('clan_id', $this->id)->get();

        return $leader;
    }
}
```

But this wouldn't be smart. Instead of this I would like to have it joined my clans table

Clans:

|id|leader_user_id|

so I can access it easily.

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `one-to-many` relations between clan and user as:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

And in your `leader()` function you can write as:

```
public function leader() 
{
    $leader = $this->users()->whereHas('role', function($query) {
        $query->where('slug', 'leader');
    })->get();

    return $leader;
}
```

**Update**

*To the response of comment below*

You can create a scope as:

```
public function scopeLeader($query)
{
    return $query->with(['users' => function($query) {
               $query->whereHas('role', function($q) {
                    $q->where('slug', 'leader');
                });
}
```

And You can fetch `Clan` as:

```
Clan::where('name', $clanname)->leader()->get()
```

Comment: But then I cant do sth like: Clan::where('name', $clanname)->leader();

Comment: What do you want to fetch User or Clan?

Comment: I want to fetch the clan, but have a reference to the leader-user, so i can access the leader user as well. Is that possible?